# How do I find the maximum one-digit integer in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the maximum one-digit integer in an array.

Let's say I have an array:

```
[-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 743]
```

The maximum integer is `1011` which I have found using:

```
Math.max.apply(0,array)
```

But I need to find a maximum one-digit integer. Is there any method to find it. The output should be `1` as per the above array.

Comment: what do You expect if nothing is found?

Comment: it would be nice to have an answer

Answer (score 4):

```
Math.max(...myArray.filter((n) => Math.abs(n) < 10))
```

Comment: can't avoid to vote down sorry ... try with  `[-26, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 220, 12, 743]`
.... `-Infinity` !!!

Comment: While it’s true that I absolutely didn’t think about that, the question didn’t specify the wanted behavior for when no one digit integer is found.

Comment: I'll revote up cause of OP lazyness, not cause it deserve, ... ups ...i cant any longer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to get single digits and Math.max to find maximum of single digist

```js
let Arr = [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 743];
let singleDigits = Arr.filter(e => e >= -9 && e <= 9);
if(singleDigits.length){
console.log(Math.max(...singleDigits));
}else{
console.log('there is no single digit number.')
}
```

Comment: Should be `e <= 9`

Comment: can't avoid to vote down sorry ... try with `[-26, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 220, 12, 743]` .... `-Infinity` !!!

Comment: @fedeghe: OP didnt said that there will be always a single digit or not. There is always a exception case. Did you find anything missing that OP asked for ? Although I have handle if single digit missing, Now I want your Up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use reduce

```js
let Arr = [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 743];
const maxOneigit = Arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  return (el > -10 && el < 10 && el > acc) ? el : acc
}, null)
```

moreover this falsy `null` allows You to clearly define what You expect from that function when no integers in the {-9, 9} interval are found

Answer (score 0):

```
B_POS = []
C_NEG = []
C_NEG_Up = []
B_POS_Up = []
def solution(A):
  A.sort()
  print(A)
  for j in A:
      if j < 0:
         C_NEG.append(j)
         if (len(str(j)) == 2):
            C_NEG_Up.append(j)
      else:
         B_POS.append(j)
            if (len(str(j)) == 1):
               B_POS_Up.append(j)
  both = B_POS_Up + B_POS_Up
  print(max(both,default = None))
```

A = [ -91, 1011, -100,184,0,-22, 473]
solution(A)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple C solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int find_max_single_digit(int arr[], int size) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        /*
         * -9 to 9 will be single digit
         */
        if (arr[i] > -10  && arr[i] < 10) {
            if(arr[i] > result) {
                result = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]= {-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 743};
    int result = 0;
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    result = find_max_single_digit(arr, size);
    printf("result = %d\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in php using the below

```
$num = [];
array_filter($data_array, function($n) use (&$num) {
    if($n >= 1 && $n < 10) {
        array_push($num, $n);
    }
});
return (max($num));
```